# Turbo info for 2006 Jeep KJ Liberty CRD diesel

Tags: diesel, jeep, turbocharger, service-manual, liberty

Have a Jeep KJ, the [2006 Liberty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeep_Liberty_(KJ)) CRD with the [2.8L turbo diesel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_VM_Motori_engines#R_428_DOHC).

It fails a smog test with a [P0299](https://themotorguy.com/p0299/) error code which the kindly person at DEQ said was a turbo bearing seal failure, therefore, planning to remove the turbo for replacement or rebuild.

Can't find any paper-printed manual for significant mechanical work. I need instructions for removing/reinstalling a turbo in this vehicle. Can someone please point me to them? I have a 10mm socket wrench, and I'm not afraid to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further investigation found:

Stock: Garrett GT2056V
Garrett# 763360-5001S
OE# 35242115F
Reman 763360-9001S
Engine# R2816K5

https://www.garrettmotion.com/turbo-replacement/installer-connect/training/ and 
https://www.garrettmotion.com/turbo-replacement/turbo-diagnostics/ as well as http://www.lostjeeps.com/forum/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=87749&start=0 and https://www.facebook.com/groups/libertydiesels/ .